# Python: How to track "correct" answer in randomized multiple choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, shuffle

I successfully built a function to prompt the user with a question, followed by randomly ordered answer choices. However, since the answer choices are now randomized, how will python recognize the user input (a number: 1, 2, 3, or 4) for the "correct" answer?

```
import random

def answers():
    answerList = [answer1, answer2, answer3, correct]
    random.shuffle(answerList)
    numberList = ["1: ", "2: ", "3: ", "4: "]
    # A loop that will print numbers in consecutive order and answers in random order, side by side.
    for x,y in zip(numberList,answerList):
        print x,y 

# The question
prompt = "What is the average migrating speed of a laden swallow?"
#Incorrect answers
answer1 = "Gas or electric?"
answer2 = "Metric or English?"
answer3 = "Paper or plastic?"
# Correct answer
correct = "African or European?"

# run the stuff
print prompt
answers()

# Ask user for input; but how will the program know what number to associate with "correct"?
inp = raw_input(">>> ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `shuffle` the list of answers, but you shouldn't, what you want to do is shuffling the list of indices... an example of implementation, just to clarify what I mean, is

```
def ask(question, wrong, correct):
    """ask: asks a multiple choice question, randomizing possible answers.

question: string containing a question
wrong:    list of strings, each one a possible answer, all of them wrong
correct:  list of strings, each one a possible answer, all of them correct

Returns True if user gives one of the correct answers, False otherwise."""

    from random import shuffle

    # the add operator (+) concatenates lists, [a,b]+[c,d]->[a,b,c,d]
    answers = wrong + correct

    # we'll need the lengths of the lists, let compute those lengths
    lw = len(wrong)
    lc = len(correct)

    # indices will be a random list containing integers from 0 to lw+lc-1
    indices = range(lw+lc) ; shuffle(indices)

    # print the question
    print question

    # print the possible choices, using the order of the randomized list
    # NB enumerate([1,3,0,2]) -> [(0,1),(1,3),(2,0),(3,2)] so that
    #    initially i=0, index=1, next i=1, index=3, etc
    for i, index in enumerate(indices):
        # print a progressive number and a possible answer,
        # i+1 because humans prefer enumerations starting from 1...
        print "  %2d:\t%s" % (i+1, answers[index])

    # repeatedly ask the user to make a choice, until the answer is
    # an integer in the correct range
    ask = "Give me the number (%d-%d) of the correct answer: "%(1,lw+lc)
    while True:
        n = raw_input(ask)
        try:
            n = int(n)
            if 0<n<lw+lc+1: break
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print 'Your choice ("%s") is invalid'%n

    # at this point we have a valid choice, it remains to check if
    # the choice is also correct...
    return True if indices[n-1] in range(lw,lw+lc) else False
```

I forgot to mention, my example supports multiple correct answers...

You call it like this,

```
In [2]: q = "What is the third letter of the alphabet?"

In [3]: w = [c for c in "abdefghij"] ; c = ["c"]

In [4]: print "Correct!" if ask(q, w, c) else "No way..."
What is the third letter of the alphabet?
   1:   d
   2:   f
   3:   a
   4:   c
   5:   h
   6:   b
   7:   i
   8:   e
   9:   g
  10:   j
Give me the number (1-10) of the correct answer: c
Your choice ("c") is invalid
Give me the number (1-10) of the correct answer: 11
Your choice ("11") is invalid
Give me the number (1-10) of the correct answer: 2
No way...

In [5]: print "Correct!" if ask(q, w, c) else "No way..."
What is the third letter of the alphabet?
   1:   j
   2:   a
   3:   e
   4:   h
   5:   i
   6:   d
   7:   b
   8:   c
   9:   f
  10:   g
Give me the number (1-10) of the correct answer: 8
Correct!
```

Comment: Thanks, gboffi. Your code is a little bit beyond my current skill, but I'm going to study the heck out of it. Preliminary question: how can I keep the code clean if for ask( X, Y, Z), the strings and lists for X Y and Z get very long?

Answer (score 2):

Why not return answerList from your function?

Then you can compare:

```
answerList = answers()
inp = raw_input('>>>')

if answerList[int(inp) - 1] == correct:
    print('You're correct!')
else:
    print('Nope...')
```

Comment: Thank you, Tomas. Very elegant solution.

Comment: You'll want to change it to `"You're correct!"` to be correct with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I used global keyword and track(list) to check. But don't know if it's a good practice or not

```
import random

def answers():
    answerList = [answer1, answer2, answer3, correct]
    random.shuffle(answerList)
    numberList = ["1: ", "2: ", "3: ", "4: "]
    global track
    track = []
    # A loop that will print numbers in consecutive order and answers in random order, side by side.
    for x,y in zip(numberList,answerList):
        print x,y
        track.append(y)





# The question
prompt = "What is the average migrating speed of a laden swallow?"
#Incorrect answers
answer1 = "Gas or electric?"
answer2 = "Metric or English?"
answer3 = "Paper or plastic?"
# Correct answer
global correct
correct = "African or European?"

# run the stuff
print prompt


answers()

# Ask user for input; but how will the program know what number to associate with "correct"?
inp = raw_input(">>> ")

if correct == track[int(inp)-1]:
    print "Success"

else:

    inp = raw_input("Try again>>> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.index` to find the index of the correct answer:

```
correct_index = answerList.index(correct)
```

Remember that indexes are 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

I placed your answers in a dictionary to maintain association and allow for shuffling of question presentation.

```
import random

def answers(question, possAnswers):
    print(question)
    answerList = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'correct']
    random.shuffle(answerList)
    for i, j in enumerate(answerList):
        print("%s: %s" %(i, possAnswers[j]))
    inp = int(raw_input(">>> "))
    if answerList[inp] == 'correct':
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Incorrect!')

possAnswers = {'answer1' : "Gas or electric?", 'answer2' : "Metric or English?", 'answer3' : "Paper or plastic?", 'correct' : "African or European?"}

question = "What is the average migrating speed of a laden swallow?"

answers(question, possAnswers)
```